# Why doesn't this way of delaying ajax work?

Tags: jquery

easy one. I just want to know why this won't work. I'm not asking for a code that works, I just want to understand why this doesn't work:

```
$.delay(500).ajax(...);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you're invoking a function that doesn't exist, so there's that for starters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery delay method only works on jQuery animations, e.g. animate(), fadeIn(), fadeOut().

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 1):

delay(), by default, will insert a delay in the "fx" queue, not generally in every jQuery function.

See jQuery queue system to better understand how it works (and how you can eventually use delay also for other calls).

Answer (score 1):

From http://api.jquery.com/delay/:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug said it all

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new d.fn.init(a,b,g)} has no method 'delay'

It works only with animations and few more events